# java indexoutofboundexpection in using grep and awk

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a file containing lines with the format of a,b,c,d,e,f.

I wrote the following Java code to return the list myextracting b,c,d,e,f by looking for b as key.

```
public static List<String> getThirdFourthFifthColumnBySecondColumnByCliTools(String filePath, String key) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String command = "grep " + key + " " + filePath + " | awk -F ',' '{print $3,$4,$5}'";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] split = line.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            list.add(split[i]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

However I receive IndexOutOfBoundExcecption in my Java.

Can anyone please point out the problem in my code?

Comment: you should provide the exception stacktrace. Are you sure this code is the part throwing the exception?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code will not throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, likely it is the user of this method that does. As an aside, are you aware that Java provides options to tokenize and parse strings? Forking out to grep and awk seems a bit odd. Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Aside: `list.addAll(Arrays.asList(split));` is an easier way to write your inner for loop.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're not doing this in pure Java? Also your pipe will not work unless you're using a shell so your command should begin `bash -c`